# Matrix elements value in fortan when not bounded

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Here is my code to print an matrix of 2 by 2

```
program matrix
implicit none
integer::a(2,2), b(2,3), c(2,3)
integer::i,j
write(*,*) "write the elements of matrix A"
! open(unit=10, file="matrix.dat")
do i=1,2

do j = 1,2
read(*,*) A(i,j)

end do
end do


do i=1,2
write(*,*)A(i,j)
END DO




END PROGRAM Matrix
```

which outputs as

Write elements of matrix A

and on input value of

```
1
2
3
4
```

It gives me matrix of

```
1    2
3    4
```

But when I replce A(i,j) with A(i,:)

Then It requires six no as input as below

```
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
```

It prints output as

```
3    4
7    8
```

Why is it so..why both output is not the same.

I am learning to understand fortan and since I couldn't find it anywhere in refrence book so can anyone help me to understand this?

Comment: The expression `A(i,:)` means *every element in row i of matrix A*.  If you execute that 4 times then it 'eats' 8 numbers (I presume that when you write *requires six no* you have forgotten to use both hands to count).  Sit down with a pencil and paper and pretend to be the computer as it executes your program.  You will learn a lot more that way than from any answer I could provide, possibly more than from anyone else's answer too.